# Верно ли здесь склонение «Севастополя» или нужно «Севастополю»?

Tags: склонение

«В преддверии начала эпидемического подъёма по заболеваемости ОРВИ и гриппом на базе Межрегионального управления Роспотребнадзора по Республике Крым и г. Севастополя будет создана горячая линия».... Верно ли здесь склонение «Севастополя» или нужно «Севастополю»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: *В преддверии эпидемического подъёма заболеваемости ОРВИ и гриппом на базе Межрегионального управления Роспотребнадзора по Республике Крым и г. Севастополю будет создана горячая линия*.

*Преддверие* синонимично *началу*, стоит оставить что-то одно, а предлог *по* управляет дательным падежом. Также обратите внимание, что у слова *подъем* беспредложное управление в литературном языке, предлог *по* при нем не нужен.

Comment: Севастополю все-таки....спасибо, так и написала.

Comment: Преддверие не начало, а то, что предшествует началу. Но в данном случае лучше сказать "в преддверии эпидемического подъема" - коротко и понятно.

Comment: @М_Г слово *преддверие* синонимично слову *начало*. Это я и имел в виду.

Answer (score 0):

(1) *Подъём заболеваемости*  а не  *подъём ПО заболеваемости*
(2) Скорее всего, линия будет создана на базе управления по г. Севастопол**ю**, а не на базе г. Севастопол**я**.  (Сравни: [День открытых дверей для предпринимателей в Межрегиональном управлении Роспотребнадзора по Республике Крым и городу Севастополю](http://82.rospotrebnadzor.ru/directions/org_dep34/146724/))
(3) Слово "начала" - лишнее.